# orchard cms why page title is empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

i use orchard cms version 1.10.2
my admin dashboard page title is shown. but my web pages(ui) title is empth.i trace document.cshtml (title variable) and result is : when open admin dashboard, title have value. but when open user web pages (ui), value is empty and not show in title of browser tab.

why my page title is null ?

i sure title of page is saved in databse, because show in admin dashboard > content .

```
@using Orchard.Localization
@using Orchard.Mvc.Html;
@using Orchard.UI.Resources;

@{
    RegisterLink(new LinkEntry { Type = "image/x-icon", Rel = "shortcut icon", Href = Url.Content("~/modules/orchard.themes/Content/orchard.ico") });
    Script.Require("Html5Shiv").UseCondition("lt IE 9").AtHead();
    string title = Convert.ToString(Model.Title);
    string siteName = Convert.ToString(WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName);
    bool isRtl = WorkContext.CurrentCultureInfo().TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;
    Html.AddPageClassNames("dir-" + (isRtl ? "rtl" : "ltr"));
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="@WorkContext.CurrentCulture" class="static @Html.ClassForPage()" dir="@(isRtl?"rtl":"ltr")">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title>
    @Display(Model.Head)
    <script>(function (d) { d.className = "dyn" + d.className.substring(6, d.className.length); })(document.documentElement);</script>
    <script>window.isRTL = @(isRtl.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());</script>
</head>
<body>
    @* Layout (template) is in the Body zone @ the default position (nothing, zero, zilch) *@
    @Display(Model.Body)
    @Display(Model.Tail)
</body>
</html>
```

please say me where is start of page loading . i can trace from this

Comment: result of more tryand trace : orchard.web/code/contents/controllers/itemcontroller . when loading my page , run this controller and display action . titlepart have value . when arrive to line 46 (var model = _contentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem);) , values be 0 !!! why ?

Comment: What shape is this a template for? Can you show the `@model` directive?